# how to create a registration form using vb.net and mysqlyog ultimate database

Tags: vb.net

my registration form is not feeding data to the database. it's giving me an error message that

> in your sql syntax check the syntax that corresponds to your SQL server version for the right syntax to use near "Lname,"Email')VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)

The following code on my registration button:

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Public Class Registration

    Private Sub users_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SystemConncetion()

    End Sub
    Private Sub Clear()
        Txtfname.Text = ""
        Txtlname.Text = ""
        Txtemail.Text = ""
        Txtusername.Text = ""
        Txtpassword.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Txtusername.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Input the UserName", "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Txtpassword.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Input the Password", "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Txtfname.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Input the First name", "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Txtlname.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Input the Last name", "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Txtemail.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select the Email", "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim Success As Boolean
        If Success Then
            MessageBox.Show("Registration successfull!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Rgistration information.!", "Registration Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
        Try
            Dim CmDSave As New OdbcCommand
            With CmDSave
                .Connection = dbconnection
                .CommandText = "INSERT INTO `users`(`Username`,`Password`,`Firstname`,'Lname`,`Email`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"
                CmDSave.Parameters.Add("p1", Odbc.OdbcType.VarChar, 45).Value = Txtusername.Text
                CmDSave.Parameters.Add("p2", Odbc.OdbcType.VarChar, 45).Value = Txtpassword.Text
                CmDSave.Parameters.Add("p3", Odbc.OdbcType.VarChar, 45).Value = Txtfname.Text
                CmDSave.Parameters.Add("p4", Odbc.OdbcType.VarChar, 45).Value = Txtlname.Text
                CmDSave.Parameters.Add("p5", Odbc.OdbcType.VarChar, 45).Value = Txtemail.Text
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
        Clear()
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So did you actually look at your SQL code code where the error message told you the issue was? It took me 2 seconds to see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `users`(`Username`,`Password`,`Firstname`,'Lname`,`Email`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"
```

There's a typo there but it's fairly obvious if you actually look where the error message directed you. That should be:

```vb
.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `users`(`Username`,`Password`,`Firstname`,`Lname`,`Email`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"
```

The issue is even more obvious if you use a tool that applie ssyntax highlighting to SQL code:

```sql
INSERT INTO `users`(`Username`,`Password`,`Firstname`,'Lname`,`Email`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
```

```sql
INSERT INTO `users`(`Username`,`Password`,`Firstname`,`Lname`,`Email`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
```